# C Can not find a working algorithm to read data from a file in different cases

Tags: c, file-io

I have actually a small problem with file i/o and finding the right algorithm to read the data correctly.  The problem is, that the "header" could look a little bit different from each file.

For example:

```
File 1.
500 500
100
Binary

File 2.
500

d500
100
Binary

File 3.
   500
500

100
Binary

File 4.
500
500       100
Binary
```

...

I’m interested to get the 3 numeric values. I tried it with `fgets` and `scanf` and also with `fscanf`...  and so one.
But I find at every try a way, where I’m not able to get the values.

Dose someone have some ideas, who I could get the values in every case?

**Edit**

```
/* Jump over the identification and comment strings. */
        fseek(in, 3, SEEK_SET);
        do
        {
            fgets(line, PREAMBLE, in);
        } while(strncmp(line, "#", 1) == 0);

        /* Save the information in the structer. */
        sscanf(line, "%u %u", &imginf.width, &imginf.height);
        fgets(line, PREAMBLE, in);
        sscanf(line, "%u", &imginf.depth);
        return imginf;
```

This works for example:

```
File
500 500
100
Binary
```

**Solution**

Her is the interesting part of the code. Now I think I get every value. Maybe the code looks a little bit smelly, I haven not made sure that the code is clean.

```
  while (a[2] == 0 ){
        fgets(line, 255, in);
        i = 0;
        while (line[i] != '\0') {
            if ((line[i] < '0') || (line[i] > '9')) {
                i++;
            }
            else {
                while ((line[i] >= '0') && (line[i] <= '9')) {
                    buffer[j] = line[i];
                    j++;
                    i++;   
                }
                j = 0;
                a[k] = atoi(buffer);
                printf("%d\n", a[k]);
                strcpy(buffer, "");  
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Greetz

Comment: This seems really broad, are you asking for an algorithm that can read in a set of 3 numbers with unknown white-space and junk characters in an unknown set of lines before reading in binary data? Or is it more general than that?

Comment: Can you post the code your tried out and the resulting places where you encountered the problems? This way we can provide you with advice

Comment: Yes, exactly. I will have a try, for the @pmg idea. It's a little bit complexly but thats okay. If someone have some cheaper ideas, that would be awesome.

Comment: This sounds very much like homework.  The answer is extremely easy for any one who has done a few C programming exercises.

Comment: @Lefteris See my **Edit**. I also used `fscanf` and `fseek`. Here I get some Problems with the characters.

Comment: @ahmed-masud Yes, your right. But I would get some Ideas how I can do that intelligent.

Comment: @Taz: if you are asking for homework help then you should tag your question as "homework". Now the is the d500 in header of File 2 an actual sample or a typo ?

Comment: It was sample and it is no homework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read character-by-character and parse the input yourself.

Something like

```
do 3 times {
    ignore anything not a digit
    read number digit-by-digit
}
// input is now pointing to the 2nd non-digit
// just after the last digit of the 3rd number
// the 1st non-digit should be saved in the variable you used in the loop
```

Comment: You know you're done with the last number only when you see a non-digit. Sop when you stop, input points after the non-digit that's after the 3rd number.

Comment: Okay, I have used your way. See **Solution** in my question.

Comment: @Taz: Ok, it's not really my way but, except in corner cases, it works. Kudos to you!

Comment: Is there a "nicer" way? I love to get more information about "nice" developing.

Comment: Thanks. Now know, that there is a isdigit() function.

Comment: hehe, but your conditions are ok too.